# exec() command woks in plain code but not within a method

Tags: function, exec, python-3.7

Could someone explain to me why exec() works perfectly fine when called outside of a method, but within a method raises the following error?

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'connectivities' referenced before assignment
```

This is an example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

CON_FILE = "sample_input.txt"


import re
AAIG_connectivities_dict = {}
with open(CON_FILE, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search("^([A-Za-z0-9]+N[DE12X]*H[DE12X]*)\s+(\(.*)$", line)
        if m:
            i_AAIG_name = m.group(1)
            s = "connectivities = " + m.group(2) + ","  ; # comma to support the single connectivities, too.
            exec(s)
            connectivities = list(connectivities)
            AAIG_connectivities_dict[i_AAIG_name] = connectivities
print(AAIG_connectivities_dict)


def load_connectivities_from_file(CON_FILE):
    import re
    AAIG_connectivities_dict = {}
    with open(CON_FILE, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            m = re.search("^([A-Za-z0-9]+N[DE12X]*H[DE12X]*)\s+(\(.*)$", line)
            if m:
                i_AAIG_name = m.group(1)
                s = "connectivities = " + m.group(2) + ","  ; # comma to support the single connectivities, too.
                exec(s)
                connectivities = list(connectivities)
                AAIG_connectivities_dict[i_AAIG_name] = connectivities
    print(AAIG_connectivities_dict)

load_connectivities_from_file(CON_FILE)
```

To generate the "sample_input.txt", do in a BASH shell:

```
cat > sample_input.txt << EOF
i    possible i-1
X10NXHX    ('X8NXHX', 2, 3, 1.0, 0.29096014803723164), ('X15NXHX', 1, 3, 0.5075369033220299, 0.017894454516959042), ('X62NXHX', 1, 3, 0.2811455233433974, 0.009912472860959547), ('X9NXHX', 1, 3, 0.12840435222669283, 0.004527209402233843), ('X29NXHX', 1, 3, 0.10270495431102347, 0.003621114290518612), ('X13NXHX', 1, 3, 0.08843022425103912, 0.0031178237787778664), ('X27NXHX', 1, 3, 0.06967097761433207, 0.0024564206699284994), ('X61NXHX', 1, 3, 0.05203985561001743, 0.001834792353398024)
X12NXHX    ('X11NXHX', 1, 4, 1.0, 0.014683671473740228), ('X32NXHX', 1, 4, 0.4498988189862975, 0.006606166454418515), ('X31NXHX', 1, 4, 0.1633848174540025, 0.0023990889832915907), ('X36NXHX', 1, 4, 0.08439509702204087, 0.0012392298786660803), ('X13NXHX', 1, 4, 0.049958867050537537, 0.0007335795909703586), ('X30NXHX', 1, 4, 0.02502771889502097, 0.00036749880199160877), ('X38NXHX', 1, 4, 0.02304040021466484, 0.00033831766737563233), ('X40NXHX', 1, 4, 0.01903733838008644, 0.00027953802250761526), ('X29NXHX', 1, 4, 0.01757512963793901, 0.00025806742971189146), ('X5NXHX', 1, 4, 0.01709261655271193, 0.0002509823660866362), ('X39NXHX', 1, 4, 0.007533665145110988, 0.00011062186398397724), ('X33NXHX', 1, 4, 0.005975869974827519, 8.774771148015558e-05), ('X41NXHX', 1, 4, 0.00046841775328956294, 6.878092401771443e-06), ('X55NXHX', 1, 4, 0.00035046651402599333, 5.146135154504658e-06), ('X35NXHX', 1, 4, 8.313139742956269e-05, 1.2206741290086314e-06)
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In Python 3 you must use a new, empty namespace in exec(). So the code should become like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

CON_FILE = "sample_input.txt"


import re
AAIG_connectivities_dict = {}
with open(CON_FILE, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search("^([A-Za-z0-9]+N[DE12X]*H[DE12X]*)\s+(\(.*)$", line)
        if m:
            i_AAIG_name = m.group(1)
            s = "connectivities = " + m.group(2) + ","  ; # comma to support the single connectivities, too.
            exec(s)
            connectivities = list(connectivities)
            AAIG_connectivities_dict[i_AAIG_name] = connectivities
print(AAIG_connectivities_dict)


def load_connectivities_from_file(CON_FILE):
    import re
    AAIG_connectivities_dict = {}
    with open(CON_FILE, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            m = re.search("^([A-Za-z0-9]+N[DE12X]*H[DE12X]*)\s+(\(.*)$", line)
            if m:
                i_AAIG_name = m.group(1)
                s = "connectivities = " + m.group(2) + ","  ; # comma to support the single connectivities, too.
                namespace = {}
                exec(s, namespace)
                connectivities = list(namespace['connectivities'])
                AAIG_connectivities_dict[i_AAIG_name] = connectivities
    print(AAIG_connectivities_dict)

load_connectivities_from_file(CON_FILE)
```